# Scala List Match Regex

Tags: regex, list, scala, match

I have a list of strings and a regex pattern. I would like to filter the the items from the list that don't match the regex. I am using the following code which doesn't seem to work:

```
val matching = token.filter(x => regex.pattern.matcher(x).matches)
```

where token is the list of strings and regex is the pattern I want to match

Comment: I think this question is perfectly fine for SO and I'm surprised it was closed without comment.  All it needs is an example string/regex to be a perfect, compact question.

Answer (score 10):

Your code should work. Are you sure your regex is correct?

```
val regex = "a.c".r
val tokens = List("abc", "axc", "abd", "azc")
tokens filter (x => regex.pattern.matcher(x).matches)
//result: List[String] = List(abc, axc, azc)
```

**Edit:**

Given your regex, make sure that the following examples match your expectation:

```
val regex = """\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou]+[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\b""".r

regex.pattern.matcher("good").matches
//res3: Boolean = true

regex.pattern.matcher("no good deed").matches
//res4: Boolean = false
```

The `matches` method will attempt to match the whole string.

Comment: yes my regex is simple,  """\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou]+[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\b""".r

Comment: Are you aware that the regex will try to match the whole string?

Comment: @user500592, what's a good way to not match against the whole string?  `regex.unanchored.pattern.matcher(string).matches` doesn't seem to do the trick.  It seems necessary to stick `.*` on the head & tail of the regex, which is pretty ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Another option for completeness:

```
val words = List("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "alphie")
words.filter(_.matches("a.*"))

res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(alpha, alphie)
```

Comment: This reparses the regular expression for each element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it like:

```
val list = List("abc","efg","")
val p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(".*")

val matching = list filter { p.matcher(_).matches }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that I've had trouble with when using Scala's Regex engine is that `.matches` will attempt to match the entire string, as opposed to doing a match on every possible substring.

In many regex engines, the following code would evaluate to a match:

`"alphie".match(/a/)`

In Scala, using `.matches` here would fail; it will attempt to match "a" against the entire string "alphie". However, if the Regex was `/a*/`, it would work, since the `*` character will match zero or many characters.

If adding repeating Regex symbols isn't an option, the `findAllIn` method might be useful:

```
val words = List("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "alphie")

val regex = "a.".r                                

//returns a tuple with the list item that matched, plus the text that fit the regex
for {
    word <- words
    matches <- regex.findAllIn(word)
} yield (word,matches)
```

Note: `findAllIn` may match a particular string multiple times, if there are multiple matches in the string.

Comment: Yes. Match means match! Not search or find.

Comment: I think @nimda is aware of that, but it's surprising that a conceptually simple concept like `regex.matchesSomewhere(_)` doesn't exist in the current API.  @nimda, one option is to use the `.unanchored` method.